# ContentObserver onChange while still working on previous onChange

Tags: android, contentobserver

My App adds contacts to the phonebook via remote command. The is no limit in the number of contacts that can be added with one command.

The App listens for changes on added contacts using a ContentObserver inside a Service. The processing of onChange() can take some time since the App needs to find which contact was updated and what fields were affected.

The problem is, when a command is received to add many contacts (e.g. 200) at once, the ContentObserver receives overlapping onChange(). This is, it gets onChange() while it is still working on a previous one. This overlap causes problems.

What is the best way to handle this?

Ideally, what I would like is: if a new onChange() happens while a previous is being processed, then discard work on the previous and start with the new one. But how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem, and I solved the problem like this, Example if you have 10 contact changes, first contact update will get `onChange` but in native contact, it will take around 1 sec, so we have enough delay to update before that if we get next contact update, it will cancel the previous timer and it will start its own so we will get run method only after all contact updated.

```
    private Timer waitingTimer;

    private Timer waitingSMSTimer;

    private Timer waitingVoiceMailTimer;

    private void sendDelayAction() {

        if (waitingTimer != null) {
            waitingTimer.cancel();

            /**
             * Timer in Java will throw IllegalStateException if you try to schedule task on a Timer
             * which has been cancelled or whose Task execution Thread has been terminated. so we
             * are making null and create timer every time.
             */
            waitingTimer = null;
        }

        waitingTimer = new Timer();

        final TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Do your action here.
            }
        };

        waitingTimer.schedule(timerTask, 1500);
    }

    /**
     * Content observer for Address book contacts change notification.
     */
    public class AddressBookContentObserver extends ContentObserver {
        public AddressBookContentObserver() {
            super(null);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
            super.onChange(selfChange);
            // We are waiting for some time, Native contact taking some time ot update, before that
            // if we try to fetch the contact, its not returning the newly added contact
            sendDelayAction();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @MuthukrishnanRajendran. I implemented your answer in my code and it solves the current issue. However, since onChange() can take really long to complete, there will be cases in which **timerTask** is already running when **sendDelayAction** is called again. I will look into how to solve this.

Comment: oh ok, For me its working fine and I did this few year before and I didn't face any problem till now, But please let me know if you find any solution. so that I can also apply in my apps.